# Why does this program crash when I try run it?

Tags: java, ontouchlistener, motionevent

I have a basic understanding of Java, but am completely new to Android Studio.  I tried making a program that increases a counter when a button is held down.  I based it on two bits of code I found (one for a simple click counter and one that used onClickListener).  Studio doesn't highlight any errors in the code, but the program crashes when I run it on the emulator.

Can someone tell me where I've gone wrong?

Thanks

Here is the xml code

````
```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="UsingOnClickInXml" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.524"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="314dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```


Here is the MainActivity code


```
package com.example.clickcounter;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int numberOfClicks = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClick (View view){
        TextView myText = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent mEvent) {
                if (mEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    numberOfClicks++;
                myText.setText(numberOfClicks);
                return false;
            }


        });


    }
}
```
````

I tried making a counter that increases when a button is held down.  I started with a click counter, which worked, but ran into problems when I modified the code to increase the counter when the button was held instead of clicked.  The program simply crashed thereafter.

The error output was

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.clickcounter, PID: 22459
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:367)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6370)
        at com.example.clickcounter.MainActivity$1.onTouch(MainActivity.java:29)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:13411)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2698)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2698)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2698)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2698)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2698)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2698)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:465)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1849)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3993)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:70)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:423)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:13674)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5482)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5285)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4788)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4841)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4807)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4947)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4815)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5004)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4788)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4841)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4807)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4815)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4788)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7505)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7474)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7435)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7630)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:188)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 22459 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Does it crash as soon as you run it, or when you click? What is the error output?

Comment: It builds successfully, but crashes as soon as I press the button.   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.clickcounter, PID: 22459
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:367)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6370)

Comment: What is the error output?

Comment: There was more, but I couldn't fit it in the comment box.

Comment: You can edit your question.

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(int)

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem.  I should have used String.valueOf.

Comment: Glad it worked, I added it as an answer.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you called `textView.setText` with an integer instead of a string.

If you call `textView.setText(1)` you would get that error - you need to convert the integer to a string (e.g. with `String.valueOf` or similar code).

When you pass an integer, it treats that as a string resource identifier and fails with a `ResourceNotFound` exception when it cannot find that resource.